# SP2013 and DR - Search App Issue

Tags: 2013, search-results, disaster-recovery

I have a custom display template and a result type that I am using to modify the display of a **people search result webpart**. The custom template and the webpart works great in Production.

Now I am setting up the DR environment which is using log shipping as a method to sync between the content databases. The site is coming up just fine **except for the people search result webpart within the site**. I get an error when I type in a query.

I found out that search configuration is not stored in the content DB (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn715769.aspx). So as per their recommendation, I followed the export/import approach to move the search configuration into the DR site but I am still not able to get any result in the webpart.

I am able to delete and recreate the webpart, then it works great. I would rather not do this during a DR failover. Any idea what other approaches I can take?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it!

The approach listed on the MSDN site (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn715769.aspx) actually works fine as recommended. My issue stemmed from the search managed properties not matching properly between the PRD and the DR environment. Specifically, the LastName managed property is not sortable OOB but I had changed it in PROD and not in DR. After changing the setting and running a full crawl in DR, the webpart worked as expected!